# object of template class

Tags: c++, templates, unresolved-external

I have a template class as follows.

```
template <typename KeyType>
class Manager
{
  Manager(std::string name );
};

template<typename KeyType>
Manager<keyType>::Manager(std::string name)
{
  //Do something;
}
```

When I tried to create an object of this class, I am getting unresolved external symbol error. Anybody tell me what is the problem with my code.

```
std::string name;
Manager<std::string> manager(name);
```

Comment: Two issues: `keyType` != `KeyType`, and are you attempting to compile the implementation in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: Sorry... This is a sample code of my project.

Comment: Yes... I tried in a .cpp file. any problems?

Comment: OK, your implementation must go in the header file, or in a file included by the header. But you should remove distracting typos from the question.

Comment: Thank you boss. Thank you posting the link too.